# Opening a Python file with VS-Code from python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I have a unique problem that I am facing right now. I am trying to create a python script that will open another python script with Visual Studio Code. I have a directory to the file location but am unable to open the program with Visual Studio Code. Does anyone know how to attack this problem? P.S. I'm using Python 3

Comment: Did you try `code PATH`?

Comment: If I try that it runs the program in CMD. I'm trying to open not run the program in VS-Code

Comment: Sorry, I'm not currently available to check it, but this is what is says [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, You should be able to do this,

```
import os
os.system('code PATH')
```

Where PATH is the path to the python file

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the issue you mentioned, Here are my steps:

1. As kprogrammer said, I tried to open another Python file in vscode using the following code.

> ```
> import os
> os.system("D:\...\data01.py")
>
> # os.system("start explorer D:\...\data01.py") 
> #  It's OK to write like this.
> ```

2. It successfully opened another python file(`data01.py`), but not in VSCode.

Then, try the following steps：

1. In a '`. py`' file, right-click '`open with`', click '`choose another app`', select `VSCode`, and check '`Always use the app to open .py files`',click'`OK`'.
2. Run the above python file again, and another python file is opened in VSCode.

If it still doesn't work, hopefully you could describe the details and requirements.